# Logarithm Series: Symbol Manipulation Proof that $\log(x) + \log(y) = \log (xy)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, power-series

Let $R$ be a ring with 1. Define a formal power series $$\log(x)=\sum_{m=1}^\infty (-1)^{m+1}\frac{(x-1)^m}{m}.$$ I would like to show using only manipulations of the power series (pretending we know nothing of exp) that for commuting $x$,$y$, we have $\log(xy)=\log(x)+\log(y)$.

(1) For sanity, this is true, yes?

(2) Assuming it's true, is a symbol manipulation proof reasonably tractable? If so, would anyone be kind enough to reproduce it here?

Thanks.

Comment: It's too difficult to do. You can prove exp(x+y)=exp(x)exp(y) using the series then use the fact that log is the inverse of exp to get the result.

Comment: The reason I ask for this method is because I am in a case where exp is not a priori surjective. So I can look at the series log(x) for x outside the range of exp. I would like to know that the propety still holds for x, y, x+y outside the range of exp.

Comment: @Cass What is your motivation here? What is your definition of exp? (The symbol manipulation proof will work -- it must work, as the quantities *are* equal -- but might require some hairy algebra. With information on your motivational issue we might be able to cook up a faster solution.)

Comment: Basically, I have some Lie subgroup G of GLn(R) on which log is defined as above. The map exp is defined as the usual power series on the Lie algebra of G. The map exp definitely hits a neighborhood of the identity, but not necessarily all of G, so I can't see how to make the "inverse of exp" proof work.

Comment: @user58512 It is actually not that difficult. As difficult, if not easier, than the $\exp$ formula.

Comment: @user58512 I agree that one cannot use $\exp$ in general. For example, the pair of functions defined in $\mathbb{Z}_2$ are $\exp:4\mathbb{Z}_2\to 1+4\mathbb{Z}_2$ and $\log:1+{\color{red}2}\mathbb{Z}_2\to 4\mathbb{Z}_2$, so we do not know *a priori* that $\log((-1)^2)=2\log(-1)$.

Answer (score 5):

This can be done formally. For details, and more, there is a nice classical reference on formal power series:

> Ivan Niven. *Formal Power Series*. The American Mathematical Monthly, **76 (8)**, (1969), 871-889.

Here is how Niven proceeds:

We verify that $\log(1+t)+\log(1+s)=\log(1+(t+s+ts))$.

For this, let $D$ be the formal derivative operator, so $D(a+bx+cx^2+\dots)=b+2cx+\dots$ and we have $D(f^n)=nf^{n-1}D(f)$ and $D(fg)=fD(g)+gD(f)$ for commuting $f,g$, etc., and $D(c)=0$ iff $c$ is a scalar (a "constant").

Using $D$, one shows by direct manipulation of series:

1. $D(\log(1+t))=(1+t)^{-1}D(t)$.
2. $D(\log((1+t)(1+s)))=D(\log(1+t))+D(\log(1+s))$.

And, from these, the result follows.

Comment: I see you're teaching calculus this semester, with all those answers... :-)

Comment: Thank you so much for the reference provided above! It is of great help!!

Answer (score 2):

Use formal differentiation to show that 
$$
\frac{d}{dx}\log (xy)=\frac{d}{dx}\log x.
$$
These are easy computations which involve Neumann series, provided they make sense. Which is true in your case, I believe, since you deal with a subgroup of $GL_n(\mathbb{R})$.

This shows that the $x$ power series $\log(xy)$ and $\log x$ are equal modulo a constant. Then $y=1$ yields the constant.

Comment: I believe the last sentence should read "Then $x=1$ yields the constant."

Answer (score 0):

Actually things goes quite directly here. Our goal is to prove the equality of formal power series
$$\sum^\infty_{n=0}\dfrac{(X+Y-XY)^n}{n}=\sum^\infty_{n=0}\dfrac{X^n}{n}+\sum^\infty_{n=0}\dfrac{Y^n}{n}.$$
The terms involving only $X$ or $Y$ in both sides can be easily verified to be equal, so it remains to show that: for every $(i,j)\in\mathbb{N}^{*2}$, the $X^iY^j$ term of $\displaystyle\sum^\infty_{n=0}\dfrac{(X+Y-XY)^n}{n}$ has coefficient $0$. Note that
\begin{align}
[X^iY^j](X+Y-XY)^n&=\sum_{a+c=i,b+c=j,a+b+c=n}\dfrac{n!(-1)^c}{a!b!c!}\\
&=\begin{cases}\dfrac{n!(-1)^{i+j-n}}{(n-j)!(n-i)!(i+j-n)!}, &\max\{i,j\}\le n\le i+j;\\ 0, &\text{otherwise},\end{cases}
\end{align}
therefore
$$[X^iY^j]\sum^\infty_{n=0}\dfrac{(X+Y-XY)^n}{n}=\sum^{i+j}_{n=\max\{i,j\}}\dfrac{(n-1)!(-1)^{i+j-n}}{(n-j)!(n-i)!(i+j-n)!}.$$
It remains to show
$$\sum^{i+j}_{n=\max\{i,j\}}\dfrac{(n-1)!(-1)^{i+j-n}}{(n-j)!(n-i)!(i+j-n)!}=0,\quad\forall(i,j)\in\mathbb{N}^{*2}.$$

Set
$$P_{i,j}=\sum^{i+j}_{n=\max\{i,j\}}\dfrac{(n-1)!X^n}{(n-i)!(n-j)!(i+j-n)!},\quad (i,j)\neq (0,0),$$
Claim:
$$P_{i+1,j+1} = \dfrac{X}{j+1}((i+j+1)P_{i+1,j} + iP_{i,j}),\quad\forall (i,j)\neq (0,0).$$
Case $1$: $i\ge j$. The possible nonzero coefficients of $P_{i+1,j+1} - \dfrac{X}{j+1}((i+j+1)P_{i+1,j} + iP_{i,j})$ are of power $i+1,\cdots,i+j+2$. We have
\begin{align}
[X^{i+1}]\left(P_{i+1,j+1} - \dfrac{X}{j+1}((i+j+1)P_{i+1,j} + iP_{i,j})\right) &= [X^{i+1}]P_{i+1,j+1} - \dfrac{i}{j+1}[X^i]P_{i,j}\\
&=\dfrac{i!}{0!(i-j)!(j+1)!} - \dfrac{i}{j+1}\dfrac{(i-1)!}{0!(i-j)!j!}=0,&
\end{align}
\begin{align}
&[X^n]\left(P_{i+1,j+1} - \dfrac{X}{j+1}((i+j+1)P_{i+1,j} + iP_{i,j})\right) = [X^n]P_{i+1,j+1} - \dfrac{i+j+1}{j+1}[X^{n-1}]P_{i+1,j} - \dfrac{i}{j+1}[X^{n-1}]P_{i,j}\\
=\ &\dfrac{(n-1)!}{(n-i-1)!(n-j-1)!(i+j-n+2)!} - \dfrac{i+j+1}{j+1}\dfrac{(n-2)!}{(n-i-2)!(n-j-1)!(i+j-n+2)!} - \dfrac{i}{j+1}\dfrac{(n-2)!}{(n-i-1)!(n-j-1)!(i+j-n+1)!}\\
=\ &\dfrac{(n-2)!}{(n-i-1)!(n-j-1)!(i+j-n+2)!}\left((n-1)-\dfrac{i+j+1}{j+1}(n-i-1)-\dfrac{i}{j+1}(i+j-n+2)\right)\\
=\ &0, \quad\forall i+2\le n\le i+j+1
\end{align}
and
\begin{align}
[X^{i+j+2}]\left(P_{i+1,j+1} - \dfrac{X}{j+1}((i+j+1)P_{i+1,j} + iP_{i,j})\right) &= [X^{i+j+2}]P_{i+1,j+1} - \dfrac{i+j+1}{j+1}[X^{i+j+1}]P_{i+1,j}\\
&=\dfrac{(i+j+1)!}{(j+1)!(i+1)!0!} - \dfrac{i+j+1}{j+1}\dfrac{(i+j)!}{j!(i+1)!0!}=0.
\end{align}

Case $2$: $i<j$. The possible nonzero coefficients of $P_{i+1,j+1} - \dfrac{X}{j+1}((i+j+1)P_{i+1,j} + iP_{i,j})$ are of power $j+1,\cdots,i+j+2$. Similarly, we have
$$[X^n]\left(P_{i+1,j+1} - \dfrac{X}{j+1}((i+j+1)P_{i+1,j} + iP_{i,j})\right) = [X^n]P_{i+1,j+1} - \dfrac{i+j+1}{j+1}[X^{n-1}]P_{i+1,j} - \dfrac{i}{j+1}[X^{n-1}]P_{i,j} = 0, \quad\forall j+1\le n\le i+j+1$$
and
$$[X^{i+j+2}]\left(P_{i+1,j+1} - \dfrac{X}{j+1}((i+j+1)P_{i+1,j} + iP_{i,j})\right) = [X^{i+j+2}]P_{i+1,j+1} - \dfrac{i+j+1}{j+1}[X^{i+j+1}]P_{i+1,j} = 0.$$
The claim is proved.

For every $i\in\mathbb{N}^*$, we have $P_{i,0}=\dfrac{X^i}{i}$, so
$$P_{i,1} = X(iP_{i,0} + (i-1)P_{i-1,0}) = X^{i+1}+X^i,\quad\forall i\in\mathbb{N}^*.$$
This implies $P_{i,1}(-1) = 0$. By induction we have $P_{i,j}(-1) = 0$ for all $(i,j)\in\mathbb{N}^{*2}$, so
$$[X^iY^j](X+Y-XY)^n=(-1)^{i+j}P_{i,j}(-1) = 0.$$